# Change attribute for a checkbox not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've got a number of input boxes , of type password across different pages. Now I have a small checkbox, which says "show password", which when it's checked, changes this from type password to text. Simple right?

Now some genius in the business has decided that for one of the pages, they'd like the button to say "hide password" instead. But only for that one page. Now in theory, this works fine but what happens is, when I'm on the page that contains "hide password", the field only changes from type text to password when I "uncheck" the checkbox. i.e. I have to click this twice. How can I get around this? It's so simple I know but it's driving me mental.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle-input="js-show-char-toggle" class="ml-small">Hide password
<input type="text" value="" class="js-show-char-toggle">
```

Show password

jQuery:

```
$('input[data-toggle-input]').on('click', function() {
    var $self = $(this),
            inputToggleClass = $self.data('toggle-input'),
            inputType = $self.prop('checked') ? 'text' : 'password';        

        $('.' + inputToggleClass).prop('type', inputType);

    });
```

You will see what I mean if you try the fiddle. If you use first checkbox, the field will only "hide" when you uncheck the checkbox. It works fine for the second one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put your code in your question please. You saw the warning when you tried to link to jsFiddle without any code and chose to try and sidestep the rule by highlighting random words as code.

Comment: @j08691 apologies, didn't see the warning. code added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use this among the different inputs:

```
$('input[data-toggle-input]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().prop('type', $(this).next().prop('type') == 'text' ? 'password' : 'text')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jyLLmkp9/3/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually cracked this using an if statement with a little help from a colleague but this is a lot shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the boolean logic switched for the inverse case.

```
$('input[data-toggle-input]').on('click', function() {

        var $self = $(this),
            inputToggleClass = $self.data('toggle-input'),
            inputType = !$self.prop('checked') ? 'text' : 'password';       

        $('.' + inputToggleClass).prop('type', inputType);

    });
```

If you add the ! to change the result it works as expected.